# Sympy second order differential equation

Tags: sympy, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve free fall equation and i dont understand what's the meaning of the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code or error messages

Answer (score 1):

It’s exactly what it says on the tin: SymPy does not have an analytic solver for these kinds of differential equations implemented.